# cannot convert from Icollection to Icollection c /cli

Tags: c++-cli

i need to fill a collection with another list in c++/cli so the problem that when i try to do that i got an error

error C2664: 'SpaceClaim::Api::V10::InteractionContext::Selection::set' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::Collections::Generic::ICollection ^' to 'System::Collections::Generic::ICollection ^'

and here the code

```
List<DesignEdge^> ^newEdges = gcnew List<DesignEdge^>();
for each (DesignEdge^edge in onecopiedBody->Edges) 
{

if (!edges->Contains(edge))
{
    newEdges->Add(edge);
}
}
cstom->InteractionContext->Selection = safe_cast<ICollection<IDesignEdge^> ^>(newEdges);  //error here
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're trying to cast from `ICollection<DesignEdge^>^` to `ICollection<IDesignEdge^>^`, which is not safe. What you should do is operate in terms of `IDesignEdge` from the start:

```
auto newEdges = gcnew List<IDesignEdge^>();
```